# Semantic Interpretation SRGS in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I am getting started with Microsoft Hololense right now and want to write a simple C# Program including speech recognition. How can i access the Tag-Value "yes" from the grxml in my c# Program? Here the code

Colors.grxml

```
<grammar xml:lang="en-US" 
     root="yesOrNo"
     version="1.0" 
     tag-format="semantics/1.0"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar">

<!-- The following rules recognize variants of yes and no. -->
  <rule id="yesOrNo">
     <one-of>
        <item>
          <one-of>
             <item>yes</item>
             <item>yeah</item>
             <item>yep</item>
             <item>yup</item>
             <item>un huh</item>
             <item>yay yus</item>
          </one-of>
          <tag>out="yes";</tag>
        </item>
        <item>
          <one-of>
             <item>no</item>
             <item>nope</item>
             <item>nah</item>
             <item>uh uh</item>
           </one-of>
           <tag>out="no";</tag>
        </item>
     </one-of>
  </rule>
```

Now the C#:

```
private async void btnStartRecognition_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create an instance of SpeechRecognizer.
        var speechRecognizer = new Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognizer();

        // Add a grammar file constraint to the recognizer.
        var storageFile = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Colors.grxml"));
        var grammarFileConstraint = new Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognitionGrammarFileConstraint(storageFile, "colors");

        speechRecognizer.UIOptions.ExampleText = @"Ex. 'yes', 'yeah'";
        speechRecognizer.Constraints.Add(grammarFileConstraint);

        // Compile the constraint.
        await speechRecognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();

        // Start recognition.
        Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognitionResult speechRecognitionResult = await speechRecognizer.RecognizeWithUIAsync();

        //Here i want to access the Tag-Value "Yes" if the user said yeah. 
        //I tried speechRecognitionResult.SemanticInterpretation.ToString

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for a UWP app, i think using speechRecognitionResult.SemanticInterpretation.Properties gives a good way to find the solution

i have found a sample:  https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i think you are working on a Windows Forms App rather than on a UWP am I right? In UWP you need to use Media.Speechrecognition rather than System.speech. So I think this solution is not compatible with UWP sadly but thank you!

Comment: yes, you have right iam using WPF, but i dont understand you have an error with speechRecognitionResult.SemanticInterpretation ?

Comment: Exactly. If I use speechRecognitionResult.SemanticInterpretation I couldnt find a way to access the value "yes". I always get the recognition result which word was said, but i dont get the tag "yes" if "yep" was said. Also i couldnt find a proper solution in C# on the net and I am searching for days now

Comment: you have to use : speechRecognitionResult.SemanticInterpretation.Properties something like this speechRecognitionResult.SemanticInterpretation.Properties[""][0].tostring

Comment: in my case speechRecognitionResult.SemanticInterpretation.Properties["result"][0].tostring   because i have written out.result = "yes"

Comment: Holy cow it worked thank you very much! I appreciate your effort!

Comment: i adapt the answer

Comment: Max , please could you post your solution for other guys  and validate my answer